# картинка вне блока slick slider

Tags: css, вёрстка

есть картинка которая принадлежит слайдер блоку
как сделать так чтобы картинку показывалось поверх блока слайдера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пытаюсь сделать через `background` или через `position: absolute;`
картинка обрезается

```css
.slider__wrapper {
  flex-direction: column;
  // position: relative;
}

.slick__slider2 {
  min-width: 290px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  box-shadow: 8px 13px 50px rgba(30, 41, 49, 0.08);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url('../img/masters-1.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 230px;
  background-position: 50% 200%;
}

.slider__image {
  // position: absolute;
  // top: 0;
  // left: 0;
  // margin-left: -107px;
  // max-width: 214px;
  // height: 350px;
  // z-index: 100;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="slick__slider2">
  <div class="slider__wrapper">
    <div class="slider__image"> <img src="img/masters-1.png" alt="img"></div>
    <div class="slider__content">
      <div class="slider__title">Nongvipa Vanasit</div>
      <div class="translate">или мастер Пат</div>
      <div class="slider__text">
        Мастер Пат - человек с очень мягкой и доброй энергетикой. Улыбчивая и вежливая тайка. Но пусть Вас не обманет ее приветливость - руки у мастера Пат сильные, как у мужчины. Слим-массаж для похудения в исполнении мастера Пат - это прямая дорога к идеальной
        фигуре.
        <br><br>
        <a href="#" class="read-full">Читать полностью</a>
        <div class="full">
          Блиц с мастером:
          <br><br>
          <span class="fat">– Что главное в массаже? </span> – Главное - это делать массаж не только руками, но и своей аурой. Энергетика человека очень мощный инструмент, она может лечить.
          <br><br>
          <span class="fat">– Зачем нужен массаж?</span> – Массаж - это возможность пообщаться со своим телом и послушать свой внутренний голос. Человек привык пользоваться телом, как машиной. Но мы не только физическая оболочка, мы - душа. Массаж открывает
          чакры, очищает ауру.<br><br>
          <span class="fat">– Это сложно?</span> – Сложно не только физически. Каждый человек - это своя аура, и чтобы массаж был во благо, нужно восстанавливать свой дух. Я читаю специальные молитвы каждое утро перед рабочим днем.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.slider__content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.slider__wrapper -->
```

Comment: ну может вы вставите сниппеты как у вас сейчас html+css? чтобы сказать что вам надо поправить.

Comment: в css 2 варианта как пытался - один закоментирвал

Comment: Если вопрос всё ещё актуален, можете его более подробно описать? Вам необходимо чтобы картинка человека не обрезалась за границами слайдера или что?

Comment: да   да  - чтобы картинка человека не обрезалась за границами слайдера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простым способом - ни как. Слик-слайдер (как в прочем и другие слайдеры) Создают родителя оббертку с position:relative + overflow:hidden; Собственно потому вы и видите только определенное количество слайдов, а не все что там есть. Как вариант можете для внутреннего элемента с картинкой задать padding-top на недостающий размер изображения. (но он добавиться всем остальным слайдам)

Comment: почему  overflow: visible; не помогает

Comment: Наверное у вас недостаточная каскадноть класса для данного CSS свойства. Но это не решение (можете убедиться задав через !important свойство). Если родитель не будет скрывать ненужных потомков, ы просто увидете все слайды одновременно

Answer (score 0):

может у вас свойство блока есть обрезающее все вне размера overflow? если хотите при наведении ховер эфект картинке а не блоку z-index свойство попробуйте, а можете блок с нужной картинкой и качеством и размером спрятать с помощью display- none , и при ховере делать видимой.